# Next.js, ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined during build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, session, next.js, jwt

I'm using Next.js 13 App router. I was storing the JWT token I received on login in session storage. I was able to access the token in all of my `page.js` pages in all of my routes if the `page.js` for that specific route/folder was a client component. This worked fine during dev, ie when i ran with `npm run dev` , but when i took the build , ie, `next build` it failed and gave me the error `ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined` .

Is it necessary that in Next.js the `page.js` for every route be server components rather than client. Are they considered as server components during build??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `sessionStorage` is browser only and you can not use browser specific API:s in server side rendered components.

Check [Why are document, window, localStorage and sessionStorage undefined in client components?](https://nextjs-faq.com/browser-api-client-component)

> The name "client component" is actually quite misleading. It's not a
> component that exclusively runs in the browser. It's a component that
> runs on the server and the client. The code inside the component is
> executed first on the server and the client or in other words, it's
> prerendered on the server and then hydrated on the client.
>
> During that initial prerendering, since the component is rendered on
> the server, it doesn't have access to the browser APIs named above.
> Hence you got that error.